# Internet connection lost after share

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-vista, internet, network-shares

We have 2 laptops:

1. Vista, working WIFI
2. Win 7, broken WIFI

We need share WIFI Internet from 1. laptop to 2. laptop by LAN.
Router or other devices are not arount, so this is only way at the moment.

So, standard right click on LAN -> Properties-> Share -> check share, OK.

Problem is that after this step start "Identifiing" on both Internet connection LAN and WIFI.
After that connection to internet not work also on 1. Laptop. 
If I check it details+specify of network connection (Details or specify maybe are not right term, I use different language settings and i dont know exactly term in English localization), WIFI has higher priority.

If i check out sharing in Lan properties, on wifi start identifiing again and after it Internet on 1. laptop work again.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, I can see that English is not your native language. If I've got this straight, you want to connect computer B to computer A with a wire and use the Wi-Fi on computer A to share the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to share your LAN connection, it's your Wifi connection on laptop 1 you want to share.

Though I would suggest rather than sharing this connection - you should consider bridging your LAN and Wifi connection on laptop 1. If this works ok then laptop 2 will get a DHCP address from the router itself and not be NAT'd by laptop 1.

Hope that is clear enough?

Comment: You can't bridge LAN and WiFi. If you could, there would be no need to configure WDS on both access points. If you try, you'll find the bridged machine unable to see any traffic from the Internet because the access point is prohibited by the WiFi spec from broadcasting traffic that isn't to one of its clients, and the bridged machine isn't one of its clients. (WiFi is *not* wireless Ethernet.)